# SSIS deploy error: Cannot find the certificate 'xxx' , because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: ssis

I tried to deploy a SSIS project to SQL server 2016 database. It shows this error: Cannot find the certificate 'xxx' , because it does not exist or you do not have permission. I login the SQL server database using Windows authentication. And my windows user has all permission on the database. How can I fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: What protection level are you using?  I believe that tells it what credentials to use for running things.  If your ID has permissions, but you are using server protection level it may be using server credentials to try to access the certificate, and the server id may not have the permissions to do it.

Comment: It is using the default level EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. And then use the same Windows user to deploy it to SSISDB.